# Orlah when planting between Rosh Hashanah and Tu Bishvat?

Tags: rosh-hashanah-new-year, fruits, tu-bishvat, orla-revai, 15th-of-av

I was under the impression that for purposes of Orlah, there are two relevant periods of planting:

1. Before Tu B’Av (Count the upcoming Rosh Hashanah for purposes of the age)
2. After Tu B’Av (Only count the Rosh Hashanah after the NEXT Tu B’Av)

However, I recently encountered the app: https://apps.apple.com/id/app/orlah-calculator/id814691761

It states there are three periods:

1. Between Tu Bishvat and Tu B’Av (Count upcoming Rosh Hashanah)
2. Between Tu B’Av and Rosh Hashanah (Don’t count upcoming Rosh Hashanah, count the next Rosh Hashanah)
3. Between Rosh Hashanah and Tu Bishvat (Two conflicting opinions cited but both seem to involve NOT COUNTING the next Rosh Hashanah?!?!?)

Case 3 is troubling me because it conflicts with my prior understanding. It also means the date Orlah ends is not monotonic; it gets sooner by planting after Tu Bishvat.

It cites an opinion of Rambam from Shulchan Aruch as option A and a Yesh Omrim from Ran, also in Shulchan Aruch, as option B, but I do not have the language skills to locate them. Credits point to Rav Yisroel Moshe Janowski as the authority cited.

Can anyone shed some light on what this is trying to reference? Is there actually a difference for Orlah between Rosh Hashanah and Tu Bishvat, or a minority opinion stating such?

Incidentally, this is a matter of practical Halacha as I am planting an etrog tree and am wondering if it would be more optimal to wait until after Tu Bishvat. (I’m aware it is rare for the tree to bear fruit before year 4, but some of the case 3 planting dates produce an Orlah period that long, with Revia extending into year 5).

Comment: I agree, that’s probably the Rambam cited, but to my eyes it looks like it means three years. To make it specific: if I plant 1/1/2024 = 20 Tevet 5784, date should be 5 Shevat 5787 (two weeks for roots). But the app says 5 Shevat 5788 for Orlah (not Revia). Maybe the app is just calculating wrong?

Comment: My reply was to a now-deleted comment citing https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Second_Tithes_and_Fourth_Year's_Fruit.9.12

Comment: Must be a mistake, or maybe the app meant to say Revai